# how to split a node in a XML file into two nodes using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Suppose I have a XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <group>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank>1</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
        </country>
        <country name="Singapore">
            <rank>4</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
        <country name="Panama">
            <rank>68</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
    </group>
</data>
```

And I want to split the node of "group" into two after "Singapore", like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <group>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank>1</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
        </country>
        <country name="Singapore">
            <rank>4</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
    </group>
    <group>
        <country name="Panama">
            <rank>68</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
    </group>
</data>
```

Is it possible to do it using ElementTree in python to do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Basically, `findall(group)` create new `group` element, copying wanted `country` to the new group, ` remove (group)`, `insert(new group)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it is easier with [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) library:

```
from lxml import etree

content = u"""\
<data>
    <group>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank>1</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
        </country>
        <country name="Singapore">
            <rank>4</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
        <country name="Panama">
            <rank>68</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
    </group>
</data>"""

root = etree.XML(content)

# insert a new "<group>" element at the end of "<data>" children:
new_group = etree.SubElement(root, "group")

# find "Panama"
panama = root.xpath('//country[@name="Panama"]')[0]

# move "Panama" into the new group
new_group.append(panama)
```

You'll get:

```
<data>
    <group>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank>1</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
        </country>
        <country name="Singapore">
            <rank>4</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
        </group>
<group><country name="Panama">
            <rank>68</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
    </group></data>
```

**EDIT**

Find all countries after "Singapore"

```
other_nodes = root.xpath('//country[count(preceding-sibling::country[@name = "Singapore"]) != 0]')
```

Move the found nodes into the new group

```
new_group.extend(other_nodes)
```

Comment: Laurent, many thanks. I have multiple nodes after Singapore. How can I move them all to the new group?

Comment: You can adjust the XPath to select all required nodes and append (extend) the new group.

Comment: For instance: `xpath = '//country[count(preceding-sibling::country[@name = "Singapore"]) != 0]'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating through each node and then storing the node with name `Panama` to a temp var and create a new `Element` and add to the root tree.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

items = """
<data>
    <group>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank>1</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
        </country>
        <country name="Singapore">
            <rank>4</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
        <country name="Panama">
            <rank>68</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
    </group>
</data>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(items)
node_panama = None
for group in root:
    for country in group.findall('country'):
        name = country.attrib['name']
        if name == 'Panama':
            node_panama = country
            group.remove(country)

new_group = ET.Element('group')
new_group.append(node_panama)

root.append(new_group)
ET.dump(root)
```

Which will output

```
<data>
    <group>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank>1</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
        </country>
        <country name="Singapore">
            <rank>4</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
    </group>
    <group>
        <country name="Panama">
            <rank>68</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
        </country>
    </group>
</data>
```